# Cursor.execute(sql) -> "TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple" with 2 arguments in parameters

Tags: python, database, sqlite, logging

I need to check wether the mail and the password (mdp) are correct when the user is logging. However, flask doesn't approve my code and tells me that I have an error :

cur.execute(sql)
TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple: TypeError: argument 1 must be str, not tuple

This is my code :

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    msg_error=""
    if flask.request.method=="POST" and "mail" in flask.request.form and "mdp" in flask.request.form:
        mail=flask.request.form["mail"]
        mdp=flask.request.form["mdp"]
        conn=sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur=conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql="SELECT * FROM Adherents WHERE Mail='?' AND Mdp ='?'",["mail"],["mdp"])
        adherent=cur.fetchone()
        if adherent:
            flask.session["log"]=True 
            flask.session["idAdherent"]=adherent["idAdherent"]
            flask.session["mail"]=adherent["mail"]
            flask.session["prenom"]=adherent["prenom"]
            flask.session["nom"]=adherent["nom"]
            flask.session["ecole"]=adherent["ecole"]
            return flask.redirect ("/home")
        else:
            msg_error="Il y a une erreur, veuillez réessayer!"
    return flask.render_template("login.html", msg=msg_error)
```

Does someone know why ?

Comment: Simply pass parameters in a *single* list or tuple: `["mail", "mdp"]`.

Comment: I tried, however I get this type of error know :    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Adherents WHERE Mail='?' AND Mdp ='?'",["mail","mdp"])
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 2 supplied.

Comment: Do not quote the qmarks! I didn't see that.